# Finding the PDF given a "probability" equation

Tags: probability, statistics

There are LED light bulbs such that the probability that a bulb still works after x months of continuous use is equal to $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$. What is the PDF for the lifetime of such a bulb? What is the expected lifetime and the median lifetime?

They're giving me the probability that a bulb still works after X months. That is the PDF, right? I think that makes sense, because it satisfies the properties: $\int_D f(x)=1$, and $f(x) > 0, \forall{x}$, but the wording is making me uneasy.

$\mathbb{E}[X]= \int_D xf(x)$, and the median is just $\int_0^m f(x) = \frac 1 2$, I believe. I'm just having trouble deciphering if I have f(x) right, with f(x) being the same as the given equation.

Comment: They provide the survival function, which is 1-CDF. You are looking for the PDF, which is just $d/dx$ (CDF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that the light bulb will survive more than $x$ months is $ \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$.

In other words, $P(X \gt x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

So, $ \text { CDF } ~ F_X(x) = P(X \lt x) = 1 - P(X \gt x)$
$ \displaystyle = 1 - \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

$ \therefore \text { PDF } ~ \displaystyle f_X(x) = \frac{2}{(x+1)^3}, 0 \lt x \lt \infty$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Since the PDF is just $\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}$ with the specified domain, we can find the median by integrating: $\int_0^a \frac{2}{(x+1)^3}$, right?

Comment: @Roggio yes, integrating and equating it to $1/2$. I get $m = \sqrt2 -1$